# constructor is not called when i create obj variables

Tags: java, class, object, methods, constructor

```
class add{

add(){
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
}
void display()
{ int s;
    s=a+b;
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
class main{
        public static void main(String arg[])
      {
            add so=new add();
            so.display();
           }

}
```

> When i run it shows that a,b are not defined while s is defined.
> The default constructor is not called while the display() function works properly.

> Apparently I was declaring the variables inside constructor. Therefore It was not working for me.

Comment: Because `a` and `b` are variables local to the constructor and hence can't be accessed from `display()`

Comment: `a` and `b` are local variables in the constructor. They are removed when the constructor finishes.

Comment: How can you run this at all?  This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: This completely broken. And your 'fact' that the constructor is not called might be slightly wrong.

Comment: I was typing up an answer and all I really came up with is that it is a very bad code example and It would have to be completely changed to be at all correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because `a` and `b` are local variables to the constructor. So, they can't be accessed outside the constructor.

Use the below code to solve your problem.

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Add so=new Add();
        so.display();
    }
}

class Add{
    int a, b;

    Add(){
        a=0;
        b=0;
    }

    void display()
    {
        int s;
        s=a+b;
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

And use the java naming conventions for class names.

Answer (score 0):

```
class add{
 int a;
 int b;

add(){

}
void display()
{ int s;
    s=a+b;
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
class main{
        public static void main(String arg[])
      {
            add so=new add();
            so.display();
           }
```

Do this like this. Make **a** and **b** accessible for display method. **a** and **b** will be automatically initialised to **0** when constructor is called.
What you are doing is declaring **a** and **b** inside constructor. 
So their scope will be upto constructor.

Comment: If you are giving an example as an answer please at least follow naming conventions.

Comment: I didn't write this by my own. I just corrected main thing.@eldo